# How to fix broken page in JSF application

Tags: jsf

I'm using NetBeans to write a web app with JavaServerFaces framework.
My faces-config xml file contains a navigation link which I use to go back to Home page.
The Home page contains slide show and a drop-down combo box which, when selected from, goes to another page.On this page is a link which returns me to the Home page.All this is fine except when I go to a completely different page and click the link to return to Home page, the combo box when used throws error and i get the dreaded

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component >>javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@6685d2dd not expected type.  Expected: >>>javax.faces.component.UIForm.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?

error.
Also all my pages are wrapped in f:view  tag.
Can anyone suggest a fix for this?
Thanks for any help.
My Home JSP Page:

```
        <title>Quotes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Quote Home Page</h1>

            <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="#{QuoteMB.createSetup}" value="Add New Quote"/>
            </h:form>
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="#{Login.logout}" value="Log Out" />
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <FORM ACTION="quoteview.jsp" METHOD="POST" >
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <h3>Please select the quote you want to display:</h3>
                <BR>


                <%
                    int count = 0;
                    int i = 0;
                    int reversecount = 0;
                    int originalcount = 0;
                    Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/babylon", "root", "sequence");

                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    //import java.util.HashMap;
                    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT quotetext  FROM quote");
                    java.util.HashMap <Integer,String> nametoValueMap = new java.util.HashMap <Integer,String>();
                    if (!resultset.next()) {
                        out.println("Sorry, no records found. ");
                    } else {
                        int j=0;
                        resultset.previous();
                        while(resultset.next()){

                        j++;
                           String qt=resultset.getString(1);
                        int len=0;
                        len=qt.indexOf("\n");
                        if(len==-1)len=30;
                        if(len>30)len=30;
                        System.out.println("search length= "+len);
                            qt=qt.substring(0,len);
                        qt=qt.replace("'", "''");
                        System.out.println("final qt= "+qt);
                            nametoValueMap.put(j,qt);
                        System.out.println("Putting j "+j+" with "+qt);
                        }
                        count = j;
                        originalcount = count;

                        System.out.println("originalcount= "+originalcount);
                        out.print("<select name=\"id\">");

                        while (count != 0) {
                            String text=nametoValueMap.get(reversecount);
                            System.out.println("Text = "+text+" reversecount= "+reversecount);
                            reversecount = originalcount - (count - 1);
                             //out.print("<option><column>" + reversecount + "</column></option>"); // where column1 is the column in the database table
                            out.print("<option><column>" + nametoValueMap.get(reversecount) + "</column></option>");
                            count--;
                        }
                        out.print("</select>");
                    }

                        resultset.close();
                        statement.close();
                        connection.close();

                %>
                <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Go" class="input">
            </div>
        </FORM>
        <br/>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <a href="javascript:gotoshow()"><img src="Shakespeare2.jpg" name="slide" id="borderimg1" ></a>
        </div>
        <br/>
</html>
```

This is the navigation rule:
`<navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/quote.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>`

This shows the links on the page that shows up when selection is made from the combobox on the home page:
`            Quote View

```
            <h:commandLink action="#{QuoteMB.listSetup}" value="Show Quotes"/>
            <br>
            <h:commandLink value="Home" action="welcome" immediate="true" />

        </h:form>
```

`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please check your code... this one MUST be obvious... Start by good indentation and you will find it very quickly....

Comment: Kukeltje-I'm sorry but I just can't see what to you is obvious. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my JSP files needed to be under the  pages folder as well as Web folder.
This is strange to me but when I copied the files to both folders the problem was fixed.
Sorry to take up anyone's time with this.
Thanks for any help.